# How to position a div differently for a specific page?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have `<div class="rightside">` on every page of my site. It positions a contact form on every page, then at 850 pixels wide screen (for responsive) it hides the contact form with `display: none;`

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 850px) {
.rightside {
    display: none;
} 
}
```

On the contact us page, I would like to make the contact form still available for this page only. How can I change  on the contact us page, so the contact form is still available for devices below 850 on contact us but `display: none;` on every other page ?

**UPDATE:**
I wish to use the attributes from .rightside in my css. I have tried:

```
<div class="rightside" id="contactpage"> in contact page
```

in the media query for 850

```
.rightside #contactpage  {
   float: left;
}
```

Comment: You can add different css classes on each page. E.g. div class="contact", div class="legalnotice", ... In css document you can access each page and provide different styles.

Comment: @AMartinNo1 Thanks, I wish to use the attributes already defined in `.rightside` as well. I have updated my question above with more details.

Comment: It cannot work as you have a space between .rightside and #contactpage. The browser assumes you want to float something with id contactpage within something having class .rightside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding another css style to your code just after the existing one, like this:

```
<div class="rightside contact"></div>


@media only screen and (max-width : 850px) {
    .rightside {
        display: none;
    }
    .rightside.contact {
        display: block;
        float:right;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your HTML, you can add an additional class to all the rightside divs that you want to disappear after a certain point, and then just use CSS selectors to remove these divs only. Change your HTML markup on all the responsive divs, so that instead of `<div class = "rightside>`, you have `<div class = "rightside responsive">`. This adds an extra class to the div that is called responsive, and from here you can just select the divs that have this class using `.rightside.responsive` instead of just `.rightside` on your media query.

**UPDATE**

The reason that the code that you recently updated does not work, is because you have a space between the `#contactpage` and `.rightside`. By having no space between the two selectors, you are selecting elements that are on the same level, and your code should work.